# How to extend jQuery.css from plugin

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, jquery-animate

I have written a very simple plugin that allows me to use `0xffccaa` format for css colours instead of `'#ffccaa'` (mostly to avoid writing quotes - but also to allow easy modification of colours by simply adding to it as an integer).

I am implementing as `$().xcss({})`, but would prefer to just use `$().css({})`.

How can I extend the functionality of the `$.fn.css` function, and are there any pitfalls I need to watch out for?

Also, I guess I will want to do the same for `$.animate`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hB4R8/

```
// pugin wrapper
(function($){ $.fn.xcss = function(opts){
    // loop through css color properties 
    $.each(['background', 'backgroundColor','background-color', 'color', 'borderColor','border-color'],function(i,v){
        // if set as number (will be integer - not hex at this point)
        // convert the value to `#ffccaa` format (adds padding if needed)
        if(typeof opts[v] === 'number')
            opts[v] = ('00000'+opts[v].toString(16)).replace(/.*([a-f\d]{6})$/,'#$1')
    })
    // run css funciton with modified options
    this.css(opts)
    // allow chaining
    return this
} })(jQuery)

// test the plugin
$('body').xcss({
    'background-color': 0xffccFF,
    color: 0xccffcc,
    border: '3px solid red',
    borderColor:0x0ccaa,
    padding:50
}).html('<h1>This should be a funny color</h1>')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/frfdj/

```
(function($) {
    var _css = $.fn.css; // store method being overridden
    $.fn.css = function(opts) {
        $.each(['background', 'backgroundColor', 'background-color', 'color', 'borderColor', 'border-color'], function(i, v) {
            if (typeof opts[v] === 'number') opts[v] = ('00000' + opts[v].toString(16)).replace(/.*([a-f\d]{6})$/, '#$1')
        })
        return _css.apply(this, [opts]); // call original method
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: That works great. I thought I tried this before posting the question, but when I stored $.fn.css in a variable, it was just storing a reference - which became a reference to the overwritten function. I was calling with `this._css(opts)` but getting errors. I don't fully understand what is going on with `apply` but it works great - thanks a bunch.

Comment: Not even close I'm afraid, but thanks for the kind words. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/aheckmann/jquery.hook/blob/master/jquery.hook.js

Based on this code for creating hooks for arbitrary functions, you can just override $.fn.css with a method that does what you want before calling the original function.

Comment: A very interesting answer/feature. There are two problems for me... 1. is it requires you to use a selector, so I used `*` to select all objects on the page which is inefficient but more importantly 2. it only operates on elements already on the page, not elements dynamically created afterwards. Here is a link to code I used to get it to work with these limitations: [gist](https://gist.github.com/1222547). Thanks for an interesting link, and an interesting answer.